# Calculadora IMC en Shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, terminal

estaba haciendo una calculadora de IMC pero estoy teniendo problemas, ya que shell me está dando fallo con la coma flotante, ¿alguien sabría como podría resolverlo? Gracias.

```
echo -BÁSCULA-
echo "scale=2; 355/113" | bc
echo "¡Bienvenido! ¡Vamos a calcular su IMC!";
read -p "¿Cuál es su estatura en centimetros (xxx cm)?: " estatura;
read -p "¿Cuál es su peso en kilogramos (xxx kg)?: " peso;
let pesoTotal=`expr $peso`;
let estaturaTotal=`expr $estatura\*$estatura`;
let imc=`expr $pesoTotal\/$estaturaTotal`
let imcTotal=`bc <<< "scale=2; $imc"`
echo "Calculando su IMC...";
#sleep 3;
echo $estaturaTotal;
echo "Su IMC es: ";
echo "scale=2; $imcTotal" | bc
```

Comment: por favor proporciona un [mcve]. Es decir, explica pasos a ejecutar tu script, qué comportamiento obtienes y cuál querrías. También sería bueno explicar qué es IMC, así como pegar el código en https://www.shellcheck.net para los errores más comunes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el manejo de decimales y simplificando tu código, podrías usar:

```
#!/bin/bash
THESCALE=2

read -p "¿Cuál es su estatura en metros? " estatura
read -p "¿Cuál es su peso en kilogramos? " peso
IMC=$(echo "scale=$THESCALE; $peso/($estatura*$estatura)" | bc -l)
echo "Su IMC es: $IMC"
```

Revisa el manual de **bc** para que veas la opción *-l* que te permite usar la librería math

```
man bc
  -l, --mathlib
         Define the standard math library
```